# Unable to Configure WireGuard to Use Secondary IP Address Instead of Main IP Address of the Server

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, iproute2, wireguard

### The Setup

**The main ethernet interface of my server is `enp8s0`, has one public IP address (`116.202.221.254`—server's main IP address), and here's how it is set up.**

```
# ip addr show enp8s0

2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:06:e6:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 116.202.221.254/26 brd 116.202.221.255 scope global enp8s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:4f8:241:55c1::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::aaa1:59ff:fe06:e66c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The route:

```
# ip route show

default via 116.202.221.193 dev enp8s0 onlink 
10.103.213.2 dev wg0 scope link 
116.202.221.192/26 via 116.202.221.193 dev enp8s0 
116.202.221.192/26 dev enp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 116.202.221.254
```

Contents of file: `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet static
  address 116.202.221.254
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  gateway 116.202.221.193
  # route 116.202.221.192/26 via 116.202.221.193
  up route add -net 116.202.221.192 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 116.202.221.193 dev enp8s0

iface enp8s0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:241:55c1::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1
```

**Then I requested an additional public IP address (`116.202.221.202`) for my server and here's how I configured it.**

Add the additional IP address to the main interface/device `enp8s0`:

```
# ip address add 116.202.221.202/32 dev enp8s0
```

Add these lines under the configuration of `enp8s0` in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
up ip address add 116.202.221.202/32 dev enp8s0
down ip address del 116.202.221.202/32 dev enp8s0
```

Apply the changes with immediate effect:

```
# ip address flush enp8s0 && systemctl restart networking
```

### Problem

All internet traffic going out from the server seems to be going out via the main IP address `116.202.221.254`. So for example, if I browsed the internet via the server, my IP address would be seen as `116.202.221.254`.

So even if I configure my tools to use the additional/secondary IP address `116.202.221.202` they seem to be going out from `116.202.221.254`.

How do I configure my server so that the two IP addresses are treated individually (not linked like they are now) and have separate routes?

### Context

I have a website on the server using the main IP address `116.202.221.254`.

I am trying to set up [WireGuard VPN](https://www.wireguard.com/) on the server (to protect my identify and overcome censorship) to use the secondary IP address `116.202.221.202` but instead once configured and set up, I am still facing the internet as `116.202.221.254`.

How do I configure my server so that my VPN will use `116.202.221.202` instead?

---

### My WireGuard VPN Configuration

*(For more context. I followed this tutorial: https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/vpn/set-up-wireguard-vpn-on-debian/)*

WireGuard Server Configuration: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.103.213.1/32
ListenPort = 51208
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp8s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp8s0 -j MASQUERADE
SaveConfig = false

# Macbook Pro
[Peer]
PublicKey = CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.103.213.2/32
```

WireGuard Client Configuration: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.103.213.2/32
ListenPort = 51208
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY
Endpoint = 116.202.221.202:51208
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

**What am I missing? How do I fix this?**

I did my best to understand each step, but it's still a lot and I know I am missing something related to `iptables` routes or rules. But the relevant information on the internet is very difficult to parse given my current knowledge and I was unable to figure out a solution despite working on this for 2 days.

*Any help is appreciated. Please try to be as detailed as possible.* Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the application itself specifies, to the system, which IP address its outgoing traffic should go through, the server will use the default (main) IP address—at least that's my understanding.

And as there doesn't seem to be a setting in WireGuard to tell it to use a specific public IP address, we need to depend on `iptables` or `ip route`.

A kind soul on `#wireguard` IRC channel helped me out with the `PostUp` and `PostDown` values in the `wg0.conf` server config that will accomplish what I need.

```
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0xCA6C/0xFFFFFFFF -j SNAT --to-source 116.202.221.202; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.103.213.0/24 -o enp8s0 -j SNAT --to-source 116.202.221.202

Post Down = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0xCA6C/0xFFFFFFFF -j SNAT --to-source 116.202.221.202; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.103.213.0/24 -o enp8s0 -j SNAT --to-source 116.202.221.202
```

This works too, but is NOT IDEAL I'm told (the `--mark` in above commands is able to target WG-specific traffic, while these are being source IP specific instead—at least that's how I understood it):

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.103.213.0/24 -o enp8s0 -j SNAT --to-source 116.202.221.202; iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.103.213.0/24 -o enp8s0 -j SNAT --to-source 116.202.221.202; iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I suspect, any given program (without specific instructions) is just going to follow the routing table.  You'd want to pay attention to the nature and order of your routes.